# Android application vs activity in the manifest

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio there is a manifest file where I can give attributes to either the `application` tag or the `activity` tag.

I'm just struggling to understand what the difference is between these two things.

1. In a tutorial I followed, orientation was fixed by forcing Portrait at the activity level. Why not do this at the application level?
2. What is the difference between giving a `label` attribute at the application level vs. the activity level? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no option to force screen orientation on `<application>`.
2. The label on `<application>` controls things like how your app appears in Settings in the list of installed apps, or any other place where we deal with things at the app level. It *also* is the default label for activities. Activities can specify a separate label, overriding the application-level default, if they so choose.

Comment: But when would we ever see an activity label? Maybe I am missing something but if I am using my phone I can only imagine ever seeing the application label

Comment: @DoubleBass: In the action bar, in the launcher icon caption, possibly in the overview screen/recent-tasks list, etc. Frequently, apps with a single launcher activity have the same label as the application. However, apps can have several launcher activities, and for the user's sake, they should not all have the same label. Also note that action bar titles can be replaced at runtime (e.g., `setTitle()`), particularly for ones that embed live information, like a search keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Question 2:
The manifest is the **dictionary/table of contents** for your android app, one of the first files that are looked at by the system when the your app is loaded/started is the manifest file

application and activity are totally different things

The **application** tag is your whole app overall(think of it as a Book), and the **label** in the **application** is your app title/name (Book title)

The **activity** tag is your context/content of your app (your Book chapters/sections), so when you define label for your activity as if you are naming that Chapter (example Chapter 1).

Summary: The **application (book)** must at least have label/title, and so **activity/chapter**, and sometimes your activities/chapters don't have titles but would be not good practice.

Question1: Its part of the Android framework (**rules**) that you have to specify what on the **activities** (**chapters**) level 1 by 1 not **application** (Book) level